# Compare the specific Data from PDF with Data in Another PDF or excel using VBA

Tags: php, excel, pdf, file-handling, vba

I want to compare some Specific data from either Two PDF file or from PDF file and an Excel File. On researching i found it is not possible  to compare PDF with Excels directly we have to get PDF converted to excel then we can compare. But There Are Issues listed down:
1. The data in PDF is not formatted and I could not find any Key/Index to Select Data from PDF and copy the data to specific Cell in excel.
2. I am Limited to Excel VBA and Adobe Reader 10.0.
3. If I want to achieve above using PHP or .net is it doable?

please suggest!

Comment: If you're limited to Adobe Reader and Excel VBA then you're out of luck. None of the two can do what you want to achieve. You'll need (potentially buy) additional software to convert the PDF into a format that is accessible to Excel. Yet, during the conversion of the PDF file the format within (and thereby possibly also the logic of the data within the PDF file) might get corrupted or misinterpreted and therefore you'll probably have to clean up the resulting data first before you can use it. Also, some PDF do not contain text but pictures which will have to be converted to text first (OCR).

Comment: If OCR is necessary then you'll have to do some more cleaning on the resulting data before you process it any further. So, in short: you might want to investigate if you can get the data in another format (other than PDF files).

Comment: Thanks Ralph. can you please suggest what technology can be used here to achieve the result. I do not have a leverage to use any market available Converters.

Comment: Move away from PDF files and get the data by other means. Data exchange using PDF is a nightmare! If you have to stick to PDF files then I wish you the best of luck, because it will get very messy, expensive, and time consuming (as described above).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some sort of third party utility, and convert the PDF files to text,
then do the comparing (then ask regarding that, one question at a time, please), for example :
[Adobe Acrobat PDF file import](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=977)

Comment: I do not have leverage to use third party Utility